# Docker network issue: Server misbehaving

Tags: docker

I am trying to resolve this network issue which I am facing multiple time while performing any docker commands like "Docker search Ubuntu".
I get an error saying:

```
"Error response from daemon: server misbehaving.
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301151/docker-pull-error) might be related

Comment: thank you lifus i tried to find the resolv.config file but i am unable to find it ! I am running boot2docker to use docker since i have a windows system.!

Comment: yep, it's *nix specific. See [this](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/docs/using)

Comment: Yeah thanks lifus ! I just did that ! its working fine ! :D

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Could you self answer your question and explain how you solved your problem for future reference ?

Comment: @Regan agree, that would be helpful

Comment: I found out that this can also be related to proxy setting, in which case cntlm might be the only solution for now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53494587/5122657

Answer (score 23):

For those who have this problem, it is typically related to having an issue with your DNS being unable to resolve `index.docker.io`. I had this issue today working from home where my internet connection has a default DNS server that is notoriously flakey.

My dev environment is OSX and I easily solved the issue by changing my DNS servers in network settings to Google's DNS servers (`8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4`) and then restarting my docker host through `docker-machine restart MACHINENAME`

Comment: Working also with Docker Toolbox on Windows

Answer (score 9):

Faster/Easier Solution: login to docker-machine and fix the dns.

Turns out you don't have to go to all the trouble and waiting associated with restarting docker-machine. Just login to the docker machine (i.e. `docker-machine ssh default`) and edit `/etc/resolv.conf` - Add the dns settings from your host machine at the top of `resolv.conf`.

This is more or less what happens when you restart docker-machine and explains why some repositories are unreachable sometimes after you switch networks.

Answer (score 3):

I also had the exact same problem. Then I stopped the docker-machine and started it--it worked.

Comment: in ubuntu: service docker restart

Answer (score 1):

My issue not solved with stated Answer here.

This is problem with resolving Host... I was getting random error `time out` and `misbehave`

You need to enable through a configuration property `experimentalHostResolver` in `%APPDATA%\rancher-desktop\settings.json`. By default this property is set to `false`, meaning that the default DNS process in the rancher desktop will be handled through `dnsmasq`. However, if this property is set to true the default DNS lookup will switch to host-resolver.

> NOTE: This feature can only be enabled for Windows currently and it is
> an experimental feature

You can take a look at the example settings.json file below as a reference:

```
   "kubernetes":{
      "experimentalHostResolver":true           <== This is the config!
   },
```

[Reference](https://github.com/rancher-sandbox/rancher-desktop/issues/1899#issuecomment-1109128277)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that, when you run this, you are connected to the internet, as Docker needs to be able to do this.