# Docker TCP lookup fails

Tags: docker, docker-toolbox

I'm very new to Docker and currently following the Docker [getting started guide](https://docs.docker.com/mac/started/), I was able to install Docker Toolbox and created by first Docker image, but now I see the following message when I try to pull a Docker image

I do `pull hello-world` from my Docker command line and I get the error

```
Pulling repository docker.io/library/hello-world
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 192.231.203.3:53: server misbehaving
```

I'm on OSX (10.10.3) and Docker version 1.8.1, build d12ea79, and not behind a firewall/proxy.

Comment: What version of `docker` are you using?   (`docker version`)

Comment: @larsks, I'm on `Docker version 1.8.1`

Comment: did you try adding google dns to your resolv.conf? `sudo echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" > /etc/resolv.conf`. This is a potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301151/docker-pull-error

Comment: @knowhy, thanks for the answer, I added the entry to my `resolv.conf` file but still Im having the same error

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue. The resolution that worked for me was to

1. shutdown and remove/delete the "default" vm in Virtual Box
2. restart Docker Quickstart Terminal
3. be sure to use `docker-machine` instead of the deprecated `boot2docker`

It doesn't seem docker has updated some of their docs to reflect NOT to use boot2docker...

side note: if you want to list your docker vms and their ip addresses run `docker-machine ls`

Just answered a simliar question here: [Why doesn't Docker Toolbox work on Mac 10.10.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32845945/why-doesnt-docker-toolbox-work-on-mac-10-10-5/32857763#32857763)

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting your docker vm either through boot2docker or docker-machine.