# Why doesn't Docker Toolbox work on Mac 10.10.5?

Tags: macos, docker

Mac 10.10.5 here. Went to the [Docker Toolbox download page](https://www.docker.com/toolbox) and downloaded the Mac binary. Ran it, and made it through to the end of the installer:

[image]

Opened VirtualBox and confirmed `default` is running:

[image]

Back in the installer, I selected "*Docker Quickstart Tutorial*" which launched a terminal:

[image]

But none of the typical Docker commands (`docker info`, `docker ps`, etc.) are working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

1. [Uninstall Docker Toolbox](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/blob/master/osx/uninstall.sh)
2. Install `brew`
3. `brew install docker`
4. `brew install boot2docker`

Then to run Docker:

```
boot2docker init
boot2docker up
```

You'll get a ton of complaints with Docker crying "*This is a deprecated tool! Use Docker Toolbox ASAP!!!*". But I'll take something that works today over something that is currently broken and *might* work sometime any day of the week my good friend.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this same issue. The resolution that worked for me was to

1. shutdown and remove/delete the "default" vm in virtual box
2. restart Docker Quickstart Terminal
3. be sure to use docker-machine instead of the deprecated boot2docker

It doesn't seem docker has updated some of their docs to reflect NOT to use boot2docker...

side note: if you want to list your docker vms and their ip addresses run `docker-machine ls`

Hope this helps someone having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the error, I knew the docker daemon is not running.

Did you start the docker machine before you run `docker info`? Seems docker toolbox is installed properly.

Related commands are:

```
docker-machine start default
eval $(docker-machine env default)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thans @BMW (+1), but shouldn't the installation of Docker Toolbox have *started* the daemon for me? Clearly the installer is broken, which is why I ended up going with `boot2docker`, which "just works".

Comment: not really. I use toolbox with mac 10.9.5, it is fine. The installation does not always start the daemon. That's why you need manually start it, and it works only in that console which you run the start and env command. If you start a new windows console, you have to re-run `eval $(docker-machine env default)` again.

Comment: I totally disagree about the UX at the very least. An installer shouldn't dump you to a screen where it just shows an error and doesn't explain why you're seeing the error. Leaves a bad taste in the user's mouth and diminishes confidence in the tool.