# After installing Docker, docker-machine env default fails because ca.pem is not found

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

Just installed Docker, but `docker-machine env default` doesn't work:

```
$ docker-machine env default
open /Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/default/ca.pem: no such file or directory
```

The path `/Users/me/.docker/machine/machines/default` exists but there's no `ca.pem` in it. Just a bunch of other files.

Comment: Does `docker-machine ls` list a machine with the `default` name?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also try regenerating the certificates for that docker-machine (e.g. default)

```
docker-machine regenerate-certs default
docker-machine restart default
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually during the creation of a machine the certs are set up. Just create a new machine from scratch like:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox dev
docker-machine env dev
```

That should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are connected to a VPN while creating the VM, that may cause networking issues that prevent the CA from being properly shared. Try disconnecting from any VPNs before creating the VM.