# Pulling docker images behind a proxy

Tags: proxy, dns, docker, http-proxy, dockerhub

I have been having trouble using docker whenever I am on my campus' wifi. Trying to pull or run an image which needs to be pulled gives me the following error:

```
Error while pulling image: Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/redis/images: dial tcp: lookup index.docker.io on 66.170.14.12:53: server misbehaving
```

My research has lead me across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28301151/docker-pull-error) post which seems consistent with what I'm experiencing, but the proposed fix has not worked. What can I do to avoid this issue in the future?

Answer (score 1):

As I explained in another context (Windows, corporate proxy), you need to set HTTP_PROXY environment variables in your Dockerfile (if your Dockerfile needs to access internet) or in your session environment variables ([in a `.profile` or `.bashrc`](https://github.com/VonC/b2d/blob/f9890cb6e1ee14842b8be2dd66a754550db793a9/profile#L16-L25)):

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://<user>:<pwd>@proxy.company:80
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://<user>:<pwd>@proxy.company:80
export NO_PROXY=.company,.sock,localhost,127.0.0.1,::1,192.168.59.103
```

Note that with docker 1.9, you will be able to leave those *outside* [Dockerfile with build-timeargument passing](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14634) (merge in [PR 15182](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/15182)).